# Serialize [Flags] enumeration as string

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, flags

Is there a way to specify that a [Flags] enumeration field in a class should be serialized as the string representation (e.g. "Sunday,Tuesday") rather than the integer value (e.g. 5)?

To be more specific, when returning the following SomeClass type in a web service, I want to get a string field named "Days" but I'm getting a numeric field.

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40
}
[DataContract]
public class SomeClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public DaysOfWeek Days;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No,  but you could define your own "enum" by creating a struct that does the same thing,

```
public struct MyDayOfWeek
{
    private int iVal;
    private bool def;

    internal int Value
    {
        get { return iVal; }
        set { iVal = value; }
    }
    public bool Defined
    {
        get { return def; }
        set { def = value; }
    }
    public bool IsNull { get { return !Defined; } }

    private MyDayOfWeek(int i)
    {
       iVal = i;
       def = true;
    }           

    #region constants
    private const int Monday = new MyDayOfWeek(1);
    private const int Tuesday = new MyDayOfWeek(2);
    private const int Wednesday = new MyDayOfWeek(3);
    private const int Thursday = new MyDayOfWeek(4);
    private const int Friday = new MyDayOfWeek(5);
    private const int Saturday = new MyDayOfWeek(6);
    private const int Sunday = new MyDayOfWeek(7);
    #endregion constants

    public override string ToString()
    {
        switch (iVal)
        {
            case (1): return "Monday";
            case (2): return "Tuesday";
            case (3): return "Wednesday";
            case (4): return "Thursday";
            case (5): return "Friday";
            case (6): return "Saturday";
            case (7): return "Sunday";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about DataContractSerializer, but with XmlSerializer it would be serialized as "Sunday Tuesday". I'm not a WCF expert, but I think I read somewhere that you can specify that XmlSerializer must be used instead of DataContractSerializer

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could think of was to create an extension method on MyEnum that iterates over MyEnum.GetMembers(), and on those which bitwise and to nonzero with the MyEnum being serialized, calling ToString() and aggregating to the output string.